# Modal de Confirmação

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Estou precisando criar um modal com um aviso para o usuário quando este clicar no botão salvar. Já tenho um semelhante que é usado para quando o usuário clica em 'Excluir' que está na minha view /Delete

```
<h4 class="modal-title">Atenção!</h4>
<div class="modal-body">
Tem certeza que deseja excluir <strong>@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Nome) </strong>?
</div>
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
@Html.AntiForgeryToken()    
<div class="modal-footer">
    <input class="btn btn-primary btn-danger" type="submit" value="Excluir" />
    <a class="btn btn-default" onclick="FechaModal();">Cancelar</a>
</div>
}
```

Controller

```
    [HttpPost, ActionName("Delete")]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult DeleteConfirmed(int id)
    {
        Curso curso = db.Cursos.Find(id);
        db.Cursos.Remove(curso);
        db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
```

Criei um model semelhante chamado 'Ciente' que é o que desejo abrir quando o usuário clicar em salvar

```
<div class="modal-body">
Apresente pessoalmente o comprovante de: @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Nome)
</div>
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
@Html.AntiForgeryToken()    
<div class="modal-footer">
     <input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" value="Salvar" />
    <a class="btn btn-default" onclick="FechaModal();">Cancelar</a>
</div>
```

CursoController

```
    [HttpPost, ActionName("Ciente")]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Createconfirmed(Curso curso)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            curso.AtualizaDiploma();
            db.Cursos.Add(curso);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Perfis");
        }
    }
```

Minha view Editor Templates Curso está abaixo. Ao clicar no Salvar desse view, deveria aparecer o modal 'Ciente' para confirmação

```
@model Competências.Models.Curso

@using (Html.BeginForm(null, null, FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-  data" }))

@Html.AntiForgeryToken()
@Html.ValidationSummary(true)
@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.PerfilId) 

<div class="modal-body">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Nome)
            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Nome, new { @class = "form-control" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Nome)
        </div>
    </div>

    <input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" value="Salvar" />
    <a class="btn btn-default" onclick="FechaModal();">Cancelar</a>
```

Minha view Curso/Create

```
@model Competências.Models.Curso
<div class="modal-header">
<h4 class="modal-title">Novo Curso/Formação</h4>
</div>
@Html.EditorForModel()
```

e meu EditorTemplate/Curso

Já criei um controller chamado Ciente mas aí o modal aparece com a informação mas não salva. Alguém pode me dizer onde está o erro e com fazer essa confirmação da forma correta?

Answer (score 3):

Está faltando dentro do seu `form` o Id do registro a ser excluído. Modifique sua View para o seguinte:

```
<div class="modal-body">
    Apresente pessoalmente o comprovante de: @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Nome)
</div>
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()    
    @Html.Hidden("id", Model.CursoId)

    <div class="modal-footer">
        <input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" value="Salvar" />
        <a class="btn btn-default" onclick="FechaModal();">Cancelar</a>
    </div>
}
```

Como o código da View modal, a mudança é bem semelhante.

---

**EDIT**

Para o caso da criação, você precisa colocar os campos como um `form` de alguma forma. Minha sugestão é o seguinte:

```
<div class="modal-body">
    Apresente pessoalmente o comprovante de: @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Nome)
</div>
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()    
    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.CursoId)
    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Nome)
    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.DataInicio)
    @* Coloque os outros campos aqui *@

    <div>Nome: @Model.Nome</div>
    <div>Data de Início: @Model.DataInicio</div>
    <!-- Mostre os demais campos aqui -->

    <div class="modal-footer">
        <input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" value="Salvar" />
        <a class="btn btn-default" onclick="FechaModal();">Cancelar</a>
    </div>
}
```

Comment: Mas excluir está excluindo e aparecendo o modal corretamente. Eu quero algo semelhante na hora de salvar também. Editei minha resposta com o modal que eu criei e o controller. Pode ver por favor @Cigano Morrison Mendez ? Grato

Comment: @JHenriqueN Editei a resposta.

Comment: Essa view que vc passou como exemplo está muito semelhante a minha view Create que é o modal que abre para preenchimento do formulário. A view Ciente tem que estar semelhante? O controller que eu passei na pergunta está certo?

Comment: É isto mesmo, mas a diferença é que os campos no modal não são editáveis. O Controller está correto.

Comment: Editei minha pergunta passando o controller Create que é o que deve chamar o modal Ciente @Cigano Morrison Mendez

Comment: Tá um pouco confuso. Qual é a View **Create** e qual é a View **Ciente**? Uma das Views não abre `tag` de `form`, então não vai salvar porque sem `Html.BeginForm()` o MVC não tem como saber quais elementos serão usados para o *Bind* dos dados.

Comment: Acrescentei os campos, mas quando clico em salvar o formulário é limpo, não salva e não aparece o Modal de confirmação

Comment: Editei a pergunta novamente @Cigano Morrison Mendez, veja se consegue entender. Caso contrário vou reformular toda ela novamente. Grato pela paciência.

Comment: @JHenriqueN Então, ainda está faltando `Html.BeginForm()` na sua View `Ciente`. Sem ele, os dados vão chegar vazios no Controller.

Comment: Não está faltando não @Cigano Morrison Mendez, é pq na hora de copiar o código aqui deixei pra trás. Até atualizei agora na pergunta. Meu 'editor template Curso' tem o @Html.BeginForm() e a Modal Ciente também está, só que ainda assim não está funcionando

Comment: Experimente colocar um breakpoint dentro de `Createconfirmed`, verifique o `ModelState`, se `IsValid` é `true` e verifique também o objeto `curso`. Pelo que você preencheu, virão preenchidos apenas `PerfilId` e `Nome`. Confere?

Comment: Não, tem mais coisa pra preencher, só resumi o código.

Comment: essa Action no meu contrller chamada Createconfirmed era o Create antes que estava funcionando. Eu mudei ActionResult de Create para Createconfirmed e adicionei o ActionName("Ciente") no HttpPost. Creio que meu erro está aí. Eu deveria manter o controller Create como estava e adicionar outro CreateConfirmed?

Comment: Bom, sem o código completo fica complicado te ajudar.

Comment: fiz o que vc falou, tirei até os outros campos que não coloquei aqui, e quando eu clico em Salvar o meu modal de confirmação não aparece, cai no mesmo formulário, só que desformatado. Tem uma diferença. O meu botão de delete não está num modal. Ele está numa página fixa. Quando eu clico nele é que abre um modal de confirmação. No casa do formulário de preenchimento do Curso, ele é um modal e para clicar no botão salvar teria que aparecer um novo modal, ou seja, modal em cima de modal. Isso pode?

Comment: @JHenriqueN Se voltou para o mesmo formulário, significa que a `Action` não passou pela condição `if (ModelState.IsValid)`, ou seja, alguma coisa está com erro de validação. Coloque um *breakpoint* sobre esta linha e verifique dentro de `ModelState` qual variável não foi validada.