# Exibir modal ao enviar um formulário

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5

Como faço para exibir um modal no momento em que envio um formulário para cadastro? O conteúdo desse modal será apenas uma mensagem. Acontece o seguinte, nesse formulário é enviado um arquivo e umas informações. Como geralmente demora alguns segundos para realização do upload, eu gostaria de lançar um modal com uma mensagem de "Aguarde", para que o usuário não mude de página enquanto o upload é realizado. No momento, não há nenhuma informação sendo exibida.

Comment: Já há perguntas no site que resolvem este problema. Procuraste por elas? encontraste alguma que te ajudasse ou parecida?

Comment: Me dê um exemplo, pois não encontrei :( @Sergio

Comment: Por exemplo: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/25147/129

Comment: @ZackMorgan Por favor verifique se minha resposta a essa outra pergunta => http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/76811/298 resolve seu problema.

Comment: @LeomardeSouza, caso esteja usando `ajax`, siga essa resposta [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21648356/jquery-ajax-beforesend-and-success-error-complete), onde ele indica a usar o `beforeSend`

Comment: Tem necessidade de ser um modal? Não pode ser um popover?

Answer (score 1):

Se você estiver usando jquery pode usar:

```
$("form").submit(function(e){
        //Ação para abrir o modal
});
```

Assim que for clicado no botão ele vai exibir o modal e assim que for feito o post a pagina vai ser atualizado para o action do form.

Answer (score 0):

Acredito que vc esta querendo utilizar um **Gif de loading**. Pois bem, vc pode usar no Jquery (Ajax), como o exemplo abaixo:

```js
//Este código fica após o Success e Error do Ajax
beforeSend: function () {
  $('.loader').css({ display: "block" });
},
  complete: function () {
  $('.loader').css({ display: "none" });
}
```

```css
/*estilos para gif de loading*/
.loader {
    display: none;
}

.loader.show {
    display: block;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 100;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    }

.loading {
    width: 50px;
    height: 57px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
}

#overlay {
    position: fixed;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.64);
    opacity: 0.8;
    filter: alpha(opacity=80);
}
```

```html
<div class="loader" id="overlay">
  <img src="~/Images/loading-image.gif" id="loading" class="loading" alt="loading" title="Aguarde..." />
</div>
```